# Problem with receive the same sha256 from float value in Java as in php

Tags: java, php, hash, sha256

I have a problem with create the same hash (SHA256) in Java as in PHP.

This PHP function

```
<?php
echo hash('sha256', 1.00);
```

returns hash

```
6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc5ed1eb8b72e8e18774c39404f9be84be00e551

My goal is receive the same hash in Java, but when I'm trying it by

```
org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex()
```

allways I'm receiving different values than in PHP. I was trying by converting Double, BigDecimal or standard float to byte array and than try to hash it. But it doesn't help. What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

php is not actually hashing the float value, instead it converts it to the one byte string "1". Just type 1 into [this online tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) to see for yourself.

In Java, you get the same result with:

```java
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(new byte[]{(byte) '1'});
```